# What's the meaning of "with" in "Trembling with fear"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the meaning of this sentence, but still, when I read the sentence, it gives me another meaning (slight different). I mean;

- He was afraid and trembling. These two actions are done together.
- But the meaning of the (Trembling with fear) is that fear has caused the trembling.
- However, they ultimately have the same meaning.
- I don't understand the meaning of (with) in this sentence.
- The women shed tears of grief. in this sentence can I replace ''OF'' with ''WITH''?
- What's difference between WITH and OF?

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic usage of ***[with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with)*** meaning:

> because of or caused by someone or something:
>
> - He ***winced with pain***.
>     I was ***trembling with fear.*** 
>     She's been at home with a bad cold for the past week.
>     I can't ***work with all that noise going on***.

(Cambridge Dictionary)